# Call plugin function outside of the plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I am using "wheel" plugin and cant figure out how to update the value and the slider.
There is an update function but I dont know how to call it from outside whenever I need to update.

Here is the plugin code:

```
var pluginName = "wheel",
    defaults = {
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.1
    };

// The actual plugin constructor
function Plugin(element, options) {
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.arc;
    this.deg = 0;
    this.element = element;
    this.handle = element.querySelector(".handle");
    this.progress = element.querySelector(".progress");
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options) ;
    this.progressFill;
    this.rad = -Math.PI / 2;
    this.svg;
    this.value;

    this.init();
}

Plugin.prototype.startDrag = function (event) {
    var self = this;

    $(window).on("mousemove touchmove", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        self.drag(event);
    }).on("mouseup touchend", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        self.stopDrag(event);
    });
};

Plugin.prototype.drag = function (event) {        
    var self = this;
    var $element = $(self.element);

    var pageX = event.pageX;
    var pageY = event.pageY;
    var touches = event.originalEvent.touches;

    // Touch device
    if (touches && touches.length === 1) {
        pageX = touches[0].pageX;
        pageY = touches[0].pageY;
    }

    var offset = $element.offset();

    var deltaX = pageX - (offset.left + $element.width() / 2);
    var deltaY = pageY - (offset.top + $element.height() / 2);

    self.rad = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);        
    self.deg = self.rad * (180 / Math.PI);

    // Convert radians to degrees relative to positive y-axis
    if (self.deg <= 0 && self.deg >= -90) {
        self.deg = 90 + self.deg;
    } else if (self.deg < -90) {
        self.deg = 270 + 180 + self.deg;
    } else {
        self.deg += 90;
    }

    this.update();
};

Plugin.prototype.stopDrag = function () {
    $(window).off("mousemove mouseup");
    this.update();
};

Plugin.prototype.keyDown = function (event) {
    var self = this;
    var step = self.options.step || 1;

    switch (event.keyCode) { 
        case 38:
            self.deg += step;
            if (self.deg > 360) {
                self.deg -= 360;
            }
            break;
        case 40:
            self.deg -= step;
            if (self.deg < 0) {
                self.deg += 360;
            }
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }

    // Convert degrees to radians relative to positive x-axis
    if (self.deg >= 0 && self.deg <= 270) {
        self.rad = (self.deg - 90) * (Math.PI / 180);
    } else {
        self.rad = (self.deg - 360 - 90) * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    self.update();
};

Plugin.prototype.update = function () {
    var self = this;
    var $element = $(self.element);
    var $handle = $(self.handle);
    var progress = self.deg / 360;
    var radius = $element.width() / 2 - $handle.width() / 2;

    var left = Math.cos(self.rad) * radius + $element.width() / 2;
    var top = Math.sin(self.rad) * radius + $element.height() / 2;

    $handle.css({
        left: left,
        top: top
    });

    self.value = (self.options.max - self.options.min) / 360 * self.deg;

    if (typeof self.options.onChange === "function") {
        self.options.onChange(self.value);
    }

    // Draw progress bar
    self.progressFill.attr("d", self.arc.endAngle(2 * Math.PI * progress));
};

Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
    // Place initialization logic here
    // You already have access to the DOM element and
    // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element 
    // and this.options
    var self = this;
    var $element = $(self.element);
    var $handle = $(self.handle);
    var width = $element.width();
    var height = $element.height();

    $handle.on("mousedown touchstart", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        self.startDrag(event);
        $(this).focus();
    }).keydown(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        self.keyDown(event);
    });

    self.arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(0)
        .innerRadius(width / 2 - 20)
        .outerRadius(width / 2);

    self.svg = d3.select(this.progress)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    self.progressFill = self.svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "progress-fill");

    self.update();
};

// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor, 
// preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, 
            new Plugin(this, options));
        }
    });

}})(jQuery, d3, window, document);
```

Here are my calls:

```
var w;
$(function () {
    w = $(".wheel").wheel({
        min: 0,
        max: 120,
        step: 5,
        onChange: function (value) {
            $(".wheel .value").html(Math.round(value) + " Min");
        }
    });
});
```

I tried

```
function setWheel(value){
    $(".wheel .value").html(Math.round(value) + " Min");
    $(".wheel").update();
}
```

This will only update the string in the html - it will not apply all the css formating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly d3 doesn't have an 'svg' attribute.
change it to d3.arc() instead of d3.svg.arc(), it crashes the code on load.

secondly, in the way the code is now your plugin is instantiated in w.data().

use: ***w.data().plugin_wheel.update***.